# I can't input in the second UITextField~~ Any one can teach me?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I make a `UIViewController`. It's a Sign in window. I use `presentModalViewController` method to pop this Sign in window. In this Sign in window's view, i put two `UITextField` with simply code, a username textfield and a password textfield. But when i run this app, a bug appeared. I tap one textfield optional, it can input at will. And then, i tap another textfield, i can't input anything any more.

```
UITextField * f1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 100, 25)];
[f1 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
UITextField * f2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 180, 100, 25)];
[f2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

[[self view] addSubview:f1];
[[self view] addSubview:f2];
```

Have anyone met this situation? please help me, thanks all.

Comment: its because the height of a textfield cannot be changed (it is always 31)and in your case they are overlapping each other.Try to put the second textfield at height say 200.

Comment: `CGRect frameRect = textField.frame;
frameRect.size.height = 100(specify the height you want);
textField.frame = frameRect;`. I just copied this

Comment: Glad to see your answers, and i tried too. But the problem still exist. I fell dejected.

Comment: I build a new project, a very simple project. It just can pop a UIViewController with presentModalViewController method. And In this view, i put two UITextField with IB only. But this simple project also can't solve above problem. So, I begin to suspect, my XCode or iOS has bug or other problem maybe. My XCode is version 4.3.2

Answer (score 2):

Give the fields a delegate connection with

```
[f1 setDelegate:self];
```

In your .h file pit the

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}
-(IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender;
@end
```

and for the fields:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
       UITextField * f1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 170.0, 300, 25)];
         f1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
         f1.text = @"";
         [f1 setDelegate:self];     
         [f1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
         [self.view addSubview:ke ti kazam zosto na telefon];

         UITextField * f2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 210, 300, 25)];
         f2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
         f2.text = @"";
         [f2 setDelegate:self];     
         [f2 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDone:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
         [self.view addSubview:f2];
}
-(IBAction)textFieldDone:(id)sender{    
    NSLog(@"textFieldDone");
}
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks, I tried this way too. But it doesn't work. I don't know how to write in UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit.

Comment: Just dont use that line dude, it is to call a method. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer your question unfortunately but I can guide you to a tutorial that might help you out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6MsPFPLeLY